# Clean domain for one of the store views

Tags: url, store-view

We have webstore with 4 different countries which are different store views in admin. 
At the moment urls are as follows: domain.com/en-us, domain.com/fr, domain.com/cz-cz etc

Client requires that one of the store views must resolve to on clean domain.com. This applies also for all content pages, products and categories of this store view, so all urls of this store view MUST NOT contain /store-view/ part in URL